# R repeat automatically: create new df if change in variable

Tags: r, loops

I have a simple grouping function that I need to apply to many different cases in one dataframe. For each character change in "scenario" I would like to create a new dataframe. Thanks for your help

```
    scenario_1 <- subset(data_ag, scenario == "0.1-0.3-0.01-1-0.3-0.35") 
    scenario_1 <- arrange(scenario_1, desc(X.step.))
```

and I would like to have something like:

```
    scenario_n+1 <- subset(data_ag, when scenario changes) 
    scenario_n+1 <- arrange(scenario_n+1, desc(X.step.))
```

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) using `dput` and show expected output based on that.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the `split()` function to break a single data frame into a list of data frames based on the value of a factor variable. Here we'll create some sample data and illustrate the use of `split()`.

```
rawData<- "scenario,x,y,z
scenario-1,1,2,3
scenario-1,3,5,7
scenario-2,10,20,30
scenario-2,30,40,50
scenario-3,50,60,70"

data <- read.csv(textConnection(rawData),stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

# since scenario is a factor variable, we can now use it
# with split() to create one data frame per value of scenario

scenarioList <- split(data,data$scenario)
```

We'll use the object viewer in RStudio to illustrate the list of resulting data frames.

[image]

To access any of the data frames in the list, use the extract operator with the scenario name:

```
# print the first data frame in the list
scenarioList[["scenario-1"]]
```

...and the output:

```
> scenarioList[["scenario-1"]]
    scenario x y z
1 scenario-1 1 2 3
2 scenario-1 3 5 7
>
```